# What is the size of the APK of the Hello world app that you get when project is first created in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I know that the size of a simple app like Hello World is less than 10 Kb as it is in here  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.helloworld.android&hl=en

But when I try to generate the APK as soon as the project is created, it shows that the app is more than 500 Kb or so.
I know that setting the minify option to true in the build.gradle, you can decrease the size of the app and when I try that in android studio, the size still is huge compared to what it should be. 
Also, Could anyone tell me what the size of the Hello World APK in their(your) eclipse is?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please check and ensure you haven't added any additional JAR or external libraries which is adding up to the size.

Comment: I haven't. Like I said, it is the size of the APK as soon as the project is created in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

That App was created in year 2013, after that there are lots of change in SDK what we are use.

May that apk was build in old **SDK** and you are trying with new **SDK.**

I think it includes size of lots of **classed and methods** which is included in **app-compat-v7**

**Edited:**
There is also another **same app** is [available in playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.v1rtyoz.helloworld&hl=en) which has **782k** :) :) created in 2014.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to reduce the size now?

Comment: Proguard settings can helps you.

Comment: Well, I've heard about the Proguard and I don't think it is available in Eclipse.. Do you think the size of APK is a disadvantage in updating